# Best free tool for video compression on Mac

Tags: compression, mac

I'm editing 'every day' videos with Adobe Premiere like holidays videos. Footages are taken from SLR cameras. I need to share those videos and of course compress it before.
Several years ago, i used to use Virtual Dub to do so but i remember that it wasn't trivial at all and i guess that other tools came up since.

In this context, what's the best free tool for Mac which performs good enough compression without huge efforts of configuration?